# Как получить определённые значения из строк?

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте!

Есть строка, которую возвращает программа:

> domain.com;0;0;0;domain.com;0

Как каждое значение, отделенное точкой с запятой, занести в отдельную переменную?
Спасибо.

**PS** Значения могут отличаться (т.е. могут быть другие цифры).

Comment: вам знакомо понятие массив ? или объект. http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/fP8gR/

Comment: @eicto, Я не знаю Javascript. Я сообразил только, как приравнять строку к массиву, а что с ним дальше делать, не знаю.

Подскажите, а можно занести строку в массив таким образом:

        var bla = string(stroka);
 var strokaarr = new Array(bla);

Comment: массив это более базовое понятие чем javascript. я пример привел как в массив положить. **hint** вам не нужны разные переменные.

Comment: @eicto, т.е. можно создать массив, как написал я, а обработать вашим способом?

Comment: зачем вам это ?

    var bla = string(stroka);
    var strokaarr = new Array(bla);

давайте может начнем с того, как вы получаете stroka, она же уже строка, массив же возвращает метод split объекта типа string

Comment: Просто мне значени stroka возращает программа на C++, она это значение записывает в файл как строка. Т.е. у меня, с точки зрения Javascript и так уже есть готовая строка?

Comment: а вы javascript на чем выполняете ? по идее конечно строка это строка. можете посмотреть `console.log(typeof(stroka));`

Comment: @eicto, всё работает, спасибо.
Оформите свой комментарий как ответ, я выберу верным.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Предположим, что в str строка заданная чем-то вроде

```
var str='domain.com;0;0;0;domain.com;0';
```

тогда заполнить массив можно с помошью методо split

```
var arr=str.split(';');
```